# Use a YUI DataSource to populate a HighCharts line chart

Tags: jquery, yui, datasource, highcharts

I want to convert my YUI2 Flash-based charts to a pure javascript implementation.  I already have a data source defined using YUI DataSource, but I have been unable to extract the data I need from it to populate my chart.
My code looks like this:

```
function setupChart(e) {

var dataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource(document.location.href + '/index/charts');
dataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSARRAY;
dataSource.responseSchema = {
fields: ['date', 'cust_view', 'cust_upd', 'notes', 'mydata_comp', 'mydata_not_completable'] };

var mychart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
  renderTo: 'chart',
  defaultSeriesType: 'line'
},
title: { text: null },
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one week
},

yAxis: {
  title: { text: null }
},

series: [
  { name: 'Viewed', data: 'cust_view' }
  { name: 'Updated', data: 'cust_upd' }
  { name: 'Notes Created', data: 'notes' },
  { name: 'myData Completions', data: 'mydata_comp' },
  { name: 'myData marked as Incompletable', data: 'mydata_not_completable' } ]


});
}
```

So, I know that dataSource holds the values I want, but I don't know how to format the syntax in HighCharts to get it out of there.

First question on SO, sorry if not clear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Be sure to upvote answers that you find helpful (including answers to others' questions). And for your own questions, remember to "check" the answer which solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the step of retrieving the data from your server.

That is done with an Ajax call. The data will be available in the *callback* function that you provide. You will create the chart *in the callback function* Not in the mainline. Eg

```
        dataSource.sendRequest("get_data.php",
            { 
          success: function (req,res) { 
                    // res.results holds the results. Use
                        // firebug to see its format
                        // The format is an array of JS objects.
                        // Each element of the array is an object with 
                        // properties from your fields configuration.
                        // 
                        // Eg
          [
            { date: "xxx", cust_view: "red",      notes: "apples", ... },
            { date: "xxx", cust_view: "green",    notes: "vegetable", ... },
            { date: "xxx", cust_view: "cherries", notes: "fruit", ... },
            ...
          ]                            
                        // create the Highcharts.chart and add the data to it
                        // here 
                   }

              failure: function () {
                       alert("Couldn't contact server");
                       }
            });
```

See examples from YUI [docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datasource/)

Comment: There is a function in the IndexController called chartsAction which is referenced in the second line of my code.  It pulls the data values from a MySQL view.  I'm not sure what goes in the get_data.php file.  I am trying your code now. ~Thanks

Comment: get_data.php is just an example url. It looks like your url is `document.location.href + '/index/charts'` Since you already set it, you may be able to use null when you call the sendRequest method. See the docs, I haven't used this part of dataSource

Comment: Thanks so much, Larry.  The 'null' worked and I'm calling the values I need now.  I was struggling for way too long on that one.  I might write up a blog post if you don't mind.  :)

Comment: Glad it worked. Blog posts are always good. Remember about upvoting and checking answers as appropriate.